# What file to use for git clone

Tags: git, clone, init

So I followed the directions at http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Getting-a-Git-Repository to create a repository and connect to it. Here is what I did:

```
git init repos
vim test.txt
git add test.txt
git commit -m "Just testing"
```

So far so good. Now I need to connect to the new repository from another system. All the documentation I read says I should be able to do that with a command like

```
git clone ssh://user@host/path/dir/somefile.git
```

Seems simple enough, however when I look at the repository I just created and search the directory, there is no *somefile.git*. There is a .git directory, but I don't think that is what they are referring to. I can't find any documentation that describes where or how this file is supposed to be created. But I know that the commands I used to create the repository (which seemed to work perfectly fine on the server) did not create any such file. Am I really supposed to point it to the .git directory, or have I missed a major step somewhere along the way?

Answer (score 0):

Generally if a repository has a name like `somefile.git` (rather than `.git` within a directory `somefile`), it's a bare repository, which is a repository which can't have a working directory (i.e. it only has Git metadata and object blobs describing the content of the repo -- the actual content isn't present in normal files). They're used mostly for storing repositories remotely, e.g. by GitHub or tools like gitolite and gitosis; to create one yourself, you'd pass the `--bare` option to `git init`.

Since your original copy of the repository does have a working directory, the repository used with the `git clone` command is its `.git` subdirectory. Therefore:

```
git clone ssh://user@host/path/to/repos/.git
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps that should work on a server called "host".

```
cd /path/dir/
git init repos
cd repos
vim test.txt
git add test.txt
git commit -m "Just testing"
```

On the other system:

```
cd /path2/dir2/
git clone ssh://user@host/path/dir/repos
```

where `/path/dir/` is the originating directory, `/path2/dir2/` is the destination directory, and `"user"` is a valid user on server `"host"`.